# Use if IE CSS in body?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm working with a really broken CMS and only have access to just below the opening body tag. I, unfortunately, had to input my CSS in there but of course now I need custom IE styling. `<!--[if IE]>` doesn't seem to be working  in the body. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Conditional comments aren't supported _at all_ since IE10. What version are you testing?

Comment: Oh wow, was not aware of that. I'm testing 11.

Comment: There is you problem :)

Comment: is the very first line of your html `<!DOCTYPE html>`? You shouldn't need to do much of any CSS customization for IE anymore.

Comment: I don't have access to change the doc type. But it turns out IE wasn't responding well to my use of em instead of px. So I was able to find a work around after all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Turnip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746736/turnip), I now know IE 10 and up doesn't allow for conditional comments.